# Firebase DatabaseReference

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 2 DatabaseReference:

- 1 is "Active" child
- 2 is "Finish" child

I want to MOVE child from "active" to "finish", but I wasn't able to do it. Any ideas how? Thanks.

I have this code:

```
public class SingleGameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DatabaseReference mDatabaseActivGame;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseFinishGame;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_game);
    game_key = getGameKey();

    mDatabaseActivGame = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Games").child("Active").child(game_key);
    mDatabaseGame.keepSynced(true);

    mDatabaseFinishGame = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Games").child("Finish").child(game_key);
    mDatabaseGame.keepSynced(true);
...
```

Inside Active child, I have `game_key` and inside, multiple child values.

I want to move it to finish because the recyclerview shows me the active child. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Following code will read value from `"your-project-root/Games/Active/game_key"`

```
// mDatabaseActivGame is still the same like in your sample
mDatabaseActivGame.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    ... onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // data is in dataSnapshot object
        // do something here
    }
    ...
});
```

Then following code will write data in `"your-project-root/Games/Finish/game_key"`

```
// mDatabaseFinishGame is still the same like in your sample
mDatabaseFinishGame.setValue(yourValueHere);
```

So combine them we get code like this:

```
mDatabaseActivGame.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    ... onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        mDatabaseFinishGame.setValue(dataSnapshot);
    }
    ...
});
```

I haven't test this myself but in theory it should work. Hope this helps